# Regex to match for zeros in string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am looking for regex pattern to find only zeros in string. string have digits separated by comma (,).

Eg.

```
'0'
     '1,2,0,3'
     '10,2,0'
```

Please help.
if String have 10 or 20, 100 etc. then it should not return the match.
I will get the string as input in procedure and I want to write some business logic based on zero present in that string. database is Oracle 11G.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: What's the case if the string was something like '0,1,0,1' or '1,2,00,3'

Comment: there will never be case for two zeros and there will be at max one zero but it can come at any place

Comment: Does the string contain only numbers? I mean can there be any other alphabet or any other character other than space?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following query on Oracle:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(',' || col, ',[^0]')
```

Comment: Thanks .. I am working on Oracle 11g and I tried both above patterns but it is not working.

Comment: @pankaj I gave you an option with Oracle using `REGEXP_LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

If your string contains only numbers, you could make use of `XMLTABLE`

```
SELECT count(CASE 
            WHEN to_number(column_value) = 0
                THEN 1
            END) AS contains_zero
FROM XMLTABLE('1,2,0,3');
```

Also, a `LIKE` statement like this should work `WHERE ',' || string || ',' LIKE '%,0,%'`

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/684)